# Feathersjs frontend and backend in a single project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I'm looking to build a small customer management portal for myself.  I've recently started working with node and vuejs a lot (coming from an html/css/javascript background).  I've really enjoyed CLI development though and am looking to build a customer management portal (nothing fancy) that has a MySQL backend.  After studying frameworks and ideas I found feathersjs which I REALLY like.  After a few hours I was able to have a REST api that returns data from my MySQL database and uses authentication.  I can get MySQL data in a JSON datasource and even do inserts, updates, deletes.  I generated the services and models using the feathersjs CLI generator.

My question is, do I really need to make two separate projects (one for backend and one for a public frontend) and run them each on a node server?  Or could I do this in as single project?   I'm still learning and reading up on feathersjs but I'm not seeing a way to make this possible. I do see a `public` folder in my feathersjs project that was generated but I don't know how to utilize it for node (I wanted my frontend written in Vue).  I can see how static HTMLfiles would work in this `public` folder.

Comment: A single server is no problem.  We do it via `webpack` and generating all the HTML/JS/etc. assets and serving them out of the public folder with standard Express middleware, with the API routes not conflicting with the UI paths.

Comment: This sounds perfect.  Can you point me in the right direction with tutorials or search terms?  The only webpack experience I really have is from what is automatically generated through vue cli or express installs.  I'm going to start researching.  Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/lewebsimple/feathers-vuejs covers most of the basics.  The key part (besides packaging with webpack) is the express static middleware in `app.js` and the history middleware to handle the vue app.